# Playing wav on iOS (with Qt C++)

Tags: c++, ios, qt, audio, wav

I have an audio recorder on iOS, implemented within QT's C++
I can record wav files and play them for example with Quick Time Player (after downloading container via Xcode)
The recorded wav files are ok, and they play the right sounds!

Now I'm trying to play them with an audio player, but this doesn't want work.
I have tried C++

```
QMediaPlayer player(this);
player.setVolume(70);

QMediaContent content(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
player.setMedia(content);
player.play();
```

or QML

```
Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 100
    color: "red"

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Play"
        color: "yellow"
    }
    MediaPlayer {
        id: playMusic
        source: "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/..long path../tmp/test.tmp.wav"
        volume: 70
        onError: {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            playMusic.play()
        }
    }
}
```

None of it wants to play the sound!

I have tried to load and read this file with QFile and this works well!
The file is there and can be readed, but the sound don't plays.

In my PRO File I have the following settings:

```
QT += widgets multimedia

QTPLUGIN += qtaudio_coreaudio
QTPLUGIN += qtmedia_audioengine
QTPLUGIN += qavfcamera
QTPLUGIN += qavfmediaplayer
```

In my PLIST I have:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Qt Multimedia Example</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Qt Multimedia Example</string>
```

I have tried some other examples from the web, but nothing works.
I have no more ideas.
Do you maybe?

Comment: Have you tried playing a 'standard' WAV file?  E.g., one recorded by other software.